# Eloquent relationships (belongsTo, hasMany) with non-default primaryKey

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, foreign-keys, relational-database

I'm new to relational databases, currently I am running a local sqlite database and simply trying to set up a a pivot/relational database where I can get a list of participants' messages by using their phone number as the primary key. There is no login, the login is essentially done by the user just by sending an SMS from their phone to the app, so I can't use typical 'id' column in my estimation. In my DB participant_id may as well be phone number. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

In my controller I simply try and DD the results using this code when I visit a predefined route:

```
public function showMessages()
{
    $participant_id = "+5555555";

    //$activeParticipant = Participant::where('participant_id', $participant_id);

    $activeParticipant = Participant::find($participant_id);
    $messages = $activeParticipant->messages;

    dd($messages);
    //$messages = Participant::find($participant_id)->messages;
}
```

I get the following error:

`SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such column: participants.id (SQL: select * from "participants" where "participants"."id" = +5555555 limit 1)`

Despite this error being present, I am pretty sure I have something wrong and I simply am not understanding what to do in the following code... if anyone could help explain this to me I would appreciate it.

Here are my models and my database migrations:
Participant migration:

```
class CreateParticipantsTable extends Migration
{

protected $primaryKey = 'participant_id';
protected $incrementing = false;

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('participants', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('participant_id')->unique()->primary();
        $table->date('appointment_date')->nullable();
        $table->boolean('subscribed');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Participant model:

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Participant extends Model
{
protected $table = 'participants';

protected $fillable = ['participant_id', 'appointment_date', 'subscribed'];

public function messages()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Message::class);
//      return $this->hasMany('App\Message', 'message_id', 'participant_id');
}
public function notifications()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Notification::class);
}
}
```

Message migration:

```
class CreateMessagesTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('message_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('phoneNumber')->nullable();
        $table->string('message_content')->nullable();
        $table->string('mediaSID')->index()->nullable();
        $table->string('messageSID')->index()->nullable();
        $table->string('mediaURL')->index()->nullable();
        $table->binary('media')->nullable();
        $table->string('filename')->index()->nullable();
        $table->string('MIMEType')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('message_id')->references('participant_id')->on('participants')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

Message model:

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Message extends Model
{
protected $table = 'messages';
protected $hidden = 'media';
protected $fillable = ['message_id', 'phoneNumber', 'message_content', 'mediaSID', 'messageSID', 'mediaURL', 'media', 'filename', 'MIMEType'];

public function participant()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Participant::class);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel attempts to guess your Model's primary key from it's name. So, when calling:

```
$activeParticipant = Participant::find($participant_id);
```

Laravel is calling `SELECT * FROM participants WHERE participants.id = ? ...`, which is returning the issue with `participants.id`, as that column doesn't exist.

Since you're using a custom primary key, you need to define that. On your `Participant` model, add the following near the class declaration:

```
protected $primaryKey = "participant_id";
```

Once that is set, the default query logic will be adjusted to `SELECT * FROM participants WHERE participants.participant_id = ? ...` and all should be golden.

Note: You may have similar issues with any relationships between `Participant` and other Models. Laravel again tries to guess what column to use for `->hasMany()`, `->belongsTo()`, etc, so double check the [Documentation for Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships), specifically the additional parameters available on those methods.

Edit:

```
//$activeParticipant = Participant::where('participant_id', $participant_id);
```

Would have worked if you added a `->first()` to the end of it to actually execute the query. Without a `Closure` (`->first()`, `->get()`, `->paginate()`, etc) you have a `Builder` instance, and not an actual DB result (`null`, a `Collection` or a `Participant`)

Comment: It seems I have to add another column to my tables which is participant_participant_id ... is there a way to change this? just want it to be maybe message_id or something like that.

Comment: I'm really not sure... Is there a reason you can't just use `id` on your `participants` model, with an extra field for `phone_number` that you can reference when creating them?

Comment: I was able to use the following syntax:

return $this->hasMany('App\Messages', 'message_id', 'participant_id');

in my Participant model and it worked! :}

Comment: Yup; that's the caveat about relationships and custom keys. Glad you got it working though :)